# I can't find "Build path" menu when I right click JAR file on Windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I want to add jar to my Android project, and I follow the instruction [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res)

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
2. Create a libs/ directory in the root of your application project.
3. Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) into your application's project `libs/` directory.
4. Right click the JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

But when I right click the JAR file, there is no "Build Path".
Any help?

Comment: Are you in Android Studio or Eclipse?  This should work in Eclipse.

Comment: I think I have the solution.I just copy jar file to my application's project libs/ directory, then fresh the project, jar I need is there.There is no need to do 4th step.

Comment: You need to be in the Package Explorer view for the context menu to appear.

Comment: You can always go into the project's properties (right-click on the project itself and choose "Properties"), navigate down to the "Java Build Path" section and add/remove items there.